# How to run two sql command sequentially in shell script

Tags: shell-script, postgresql

I would like to run the two sql commands sequentially but i can't able to achieve it.

Here is my shell script

```
#! /bin/bash

gsutil cp gs://api-bucket-germany/order_status.csv ./order_status.csv

psql -d apidbgermany -U apidbgermany << EOF

DELETE FROM apidbgermany.order_status
\copy apidbgermany.order_status from './order_status.csv' delimiter ',' CSV;
EOF
```

It is executing copy then delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely failing all together; you are missing a `;` at the end of your `DELETE` statement. Try:

```
#! /bin/bash

gsutil cp gs://api-bucket-germany/order_status.csv ./order_status.csv

psql -d apidbgermany -U apidbgermany << EOF

DELETE FROM apidbgermany.order_status;
\copy apidbgermany.order_status from './order_status.csv' delimiter ',' CSV;
EOF
```

For debugging scripts it's generally helpful to run the commands manually first by connecting and cut-and-pasting the script `sql` to make sure it works before trying it in the script.